# Скомпилировать и подключить GDAL к Qt

Tags: c++, qt, lib

Пытаюсь начать пользоваться библиотекой GDAL. Скачал исходники и скомпилировал их по инструкции. Появилось несколько файлов: "libgdal-20.dll", "libgdal.a", "libgdal.dll.a", "libgdal.la". Положил их в "D:/gdal/lib". Создаю "Qt widget project", в мэйне у меня:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <ogrsf_frmts.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GDALAllRegister();
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

В .про файле у меня:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/gdal/include/
LIBS += D:/gdal/lib/libgdal-20.dll
```

Когда запускаю проект, то пишет:

```
19:24:08: Starting D:\Interface\Work\Qt\build-WidgetGDAL-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\WidgetGDAL.exe...
19:24:08: The program has unexpectedly finished.
19:24:08: The process was ended forcefully.
19:24:08: D:/Interface/Work/Qt/build-WidgetGDAL-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_MinGW_64_bit-Release/release/WidgetGDAL.exe crashed.
```

Помогите разобраться, как запустить, или хотя бы найти причину.

Comment: Собралось нормально? А для работы не требуется libgdal.dll? Если да, то необходимо в настройках проекта в редакторе, или в переменных окружения указать путь к данной dll

Comment: Верно. Положил в  папку с екзешником либу  "libgdal-20.dll" и все заработало. Значит, либо так, либо указывать в настройках редактора или переменных окружения. Спасибо.